# Spring @RestController custom JSON deserializer

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson, spring-boot

I want to use custom JSON deserializer for some classes(**Role** here) but I can't get it working. The custom deserializer just isn't called.

I use Spring Boot 1.2.

Deserializer:

```
public class ModelDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Role> {

    @Override
    public Role deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return null; // this is what should be called but it isn't
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
public class RoleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/role", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object createRole(Role role) {
        // ... this is called
    }
}
```

1. `@JsonDeserialize` on Role

   ```
   @JsonDeserialize(using = ModelDeserializer.class)
   public class Role extends Model {

   }
   ```
2. `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` bean in Java Config

   ```
   @Bean
   public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonBuilder() {
       Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder = new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder();
       builder.deserializerByType(Role.class, new ModelDeserializer());
       return builder;
   }
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** It is probably caused by `@RestController` because it works with `@Controller`...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

First of all you don't need to override `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` to add custom deserializer. This approach should be used when you can't add `@JsonDeserialize` annotation. You should use `@JsonDeserialize` or override `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder`.

What is missed is the `@RequestBody` annotation:

```
@RestController
public class JacksonCustomDesRestEndpoint {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/role", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Object createRole(@RequestBody Role role) {
        return role;
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = RoleDeserializer.class)
public class Role {
    // ......
}

public class RoleDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Role> {
    @Override
    public Role deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // .................
        return something;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to do the same, the only difference is that I have a get method and in my pojo object I use a Date type with @JsonDeserialize, but when I run the method I get an http 400. (spring 4.1.7 y jackson 2.7.4)

Answer (score 1):

There is also another pretty interesting solution which can be helpful in case when you want to modify your JSON body before calling default deserializer. And let's imagine that you need to use some additional bean for that (use `@Autowire` mechanism)

Let's image situation, that you have the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/order/product", method = POST)
public <T extends OrderProductInterface> RestGenericResponse orderProduct(@RequestBody @Valid T data) {
    orderService.orderProduct(data);
    return generateResponse();
}
```

Where `OrderProductInterface` is:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonSerialize(include = NON_EMPTY)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, visible = true, property = "providerType")
@JsonSubTypes({
              @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = OrderProductForARequestData.class, name = "A")
          })
public interface OrderProductInterface{}
```

The code above will provide dynamic deserialization base on filed `providerType` and validation according to concrete implementation. For better grasp, consider that `OrderProductForARequestData` can be something like that:

```
public class OrderProductForARequestData implements OrderProductInterface {

    @NotBlank(message = "is mandatory field.")
    @Getter @Setter
    private String providerId;

    @NotBlank(message = "is mandatory field.")
    @Getter @Setter
    private String providerType;

    @NotBlank(message = "is mandatory field.")
    @Getter @Setter
    private String productToOrder;

}
```

And let's image now that we want to init somehow `providerType` (enrich input) **before default deserialization will be executed.** so the object will be deserialized properly according to the rule in `OrderProductInterface`.
To do that you can just modify your `@Configuration` class in the following way:

```
//here can be any annotation which will enable MVC/Boot 
@Configuration
public class YourConfiguration{

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @Autowired
    private ProviderService providerService;

    @Override
    public void setup() {
        super.setup();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.setDeserializerModifier(new BeanDeserializerModifier() {
            @Override
            public JsonDeserializer<?> modifyDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonDeserializer<?> deserializer) {

                if (beanDesc.getBeanClass() == OrderProductInterface.class) {
                    return new OrderProductInterfaceDeserializer(providerService, beanDesc);
                }
                return deserializer;
            }
        });

        mapper.registerModule(module);
    }

    public static class OrderProductInterfaceDeserializer extends AbstractDeserializer {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 7923585097068641765L;

            private final ProviderService providerService;

            OrderProductInterfaceDeserializer(roviderService providerService, BeanDescription beanDescription) {
                super(beanDescription);
                this.providerService = providerService;
            }

            @Override
            public Object deserializeWithType(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext context, TypeDeserializer typeDeserializer) throws IOException {
                ObjectCodec oc = p.getCodec();
                JsonNode node = oc.readTree(p);

                //Let's image that we have some identifier for provider type and we want to detect it
                JsonNode tmp = node.get("providerId");
                Assert.notNull(tmp, "'providerId' is mandatory field");
                String providerId = tmp.textValue();
                Assert.hasText(providerId, "'providerId' can't be empty");

                // Modify node
                ((ObjectNode) node).put("providerType",providerService.getProvider(providerId));

                JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JsonFactory();
                JsonParser newParser = jsonFactory.createParser(node.toString());
                newParser.nextToken();

                return super.deserializeWithType(newParser, context, typeDeserializer);

           }

      }
}
```