# Is there a better method than ListWrapper to bind a List<T> in a Spring MVC method?

Tags: spring-mvc

In order to retrieve a list in a Spring MVC application I would like to write something like:

```
public String myMethod(@RequestParam("foo") List<FooUi> foos)
```

But the only solution I've found so far is the following :

```
public String myMethod(FooListWrapperUi fooListWrapperUi)
```

I don't like this solution because I have to write a wrapper each time I need to retrieve a list. In this example, the wrapper is the following :

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class FooListWrapperUi
{
    private ArrayList<FooUi> fooList; 
}
```

So my question is, is it possible to use something like the first solution or is it impossible and I need to write a wrapper?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that `FooUi` is not a basic type, you probably want to create a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to tell Spring how to create `FooUi` or `Collection<FooUi>` from request parameters.

Comment: I'm really surprised there are no examples for that on the web. Spring MVC docs is so huge, I can't find what I need. Does someone have already done something like this?

Comment: Pretty basic tutorial here: http://geekabyte.blogspot.com/2014/08/how-to-inject-objects-into-spring-mvc.html .  Various answers to similar questions on SO, but none that I know of for your specific use case.  Should be simple enough to implement, you just need to identify whether your method parameter is a single object or a collection.

Comment: Ok, I will carefully read this. I didn't mention it but I am using Jackson in my project. Maybe Jackson is natively able to convert this?

Answer (score 1):

You can accommodate your use case by creating your own `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`:

```
public class FooUiResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override 
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return (methodParameter.getParameterType().equals(FooUi.class) || 
            (methodParameter instanceof Collection<?> && ((ParameterizedType) methodParameter.getParameterType().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0] == FooUi.class));
    }

    @Override 
    public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter,
        ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer, NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest,
        WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {
        // Create instances of FooUi by accessing requests parameters in nativeWebRequest.getParameterMap()
    }
}
```

The actual implementation will depend on how you would create one or more `FooUi` instances from the request parameters or body.  You then need to register `FooUiResolver` in your servlet config:

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers){
    argumentResolvers.add(new FooUiResolver());
    super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
}
```

Once registered, you can use `FooUi` in your controller method arguments without `RequestParam` or any other annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo")
public String myMethod(List<FooUi> foos){}
```

Comment: That looks very good! Thank you! Now, it's needed to be more generic. I will search for something that works with any types: FooUi, BarUi, AnythingUi...

Comment: There is nothing that says that you can't have a single `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` handle more than one type, you just have to code the logic into it.  The `supportsParameter()` method could check if the parameter type extends `GenericUi` or some such class, or is annotated with a custom annotation like `@GenericUi`.

Comment: I mean, I'd like `supportsParameter` method to handle each `Collection<?>`. Then in the `resolveArgument` method it should automaticaly populate my `Collection<?>` thanks to the Jackson library.

Comment: I see.  In that case you probably need to look into writing a custom deserializer.  Here is one such example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550376/spring-restcontroller-custom-json-deserializer

Comment: I am surprised this is not implemented in Spring Framework. I've read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441557/rest-with-spring-and-jackson-full-data-binding#comment-35822144) which says it is supposed to worked natively since spring team have corrected it. But when I test
`public String myMethod(@RequestMapping List<FooUi> foos)` 
I get this error : 'Required request body content is missing'