# Give Jackson information about Java Generics for Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, generics, jackson

I have a controller that looks something like this:

```java
    class GenericController<T> {

    private final Class<T> resolvedClass;

    GenericNostimizeController(Class<T> resolvedClass) {
        this.resolvedClass = resolvedClass;
    }


    @PostMapping("/")
    public T handle(@RequestBody final T object) {
        //doStuff that requires resolvedClass
    }
```

In some other place of my code, I'm checking a list of classes (that I cannot know in advance) and, for each of them, I'm creating a new instance of the `GenericController` class and registering it programmatically in a custom `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`. So, for example, I would do this:

```java
  Class<?> resolvedClass = //something that gives me the class
  GenericController<?> controller = new GenericController<>(resolvedClass);
  //register it programmatically
```

The problem is that my code in `handle()` requires an instance of resolvedClass but, due to type erasure, Jackson deserializes to `Object`, giving me an instance of `LinkedHashMap` that breaks my code at runtime.

My current solution uses a workaround, where I receive the object as a String and then I use ObjectMapper explicitly to get the instance:

```java
 @PostMapping("/")
 public T handle(@RequestBody final String object) {
   T deserializedObject = objectMapper.readValue(object, resolvedClass);
   //doStuff that requires resolvedClass
 }
```

I was just wondering if there's any way I can indicate Jackson the type I want on the method as the current workaround isn't ideal and causes some integration issues on my code.

Comment: I think you could fashion something out with this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47592315/4896651

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the solution: does it requires the request to have some extra fields populated indicating the type so then a custom Deserializer can do the job? If so, I'm afraid I cannot modify the incoming request to pass those identifiers.